# Advanced class features and C++ standard libraries, some questions about example

Tags: c++, class, signals-slots

Im having trouble to understand some advanced feature of c++.
Im trying to code my own signals/slots system,found exaple and run into some questions:

- `Signal() : current_id_(0) {}` - is it some sort of derived class ? what does 0 means here ?
- `int connect_member(T *inst, void (T::*func)(Args...)) {` - what does "T::" do here ?
- `mutable std::map<int, std::function<void(Args...)>> slots_;` - whats happenning when "slots_" called ?

  in this example.

  ```
  #ifndef SIGNAL_HPP
  #define SIGNAL_HPP

  #include <functional>
  #include <map>

  // A signal object may call multiple slots with the
  // same signature. You can connect functions to the signal
  // which will be called when the emit() method on the
  // signal object is invoked. Any argument passed to emit()
  // will be passed to the given functions.

  template <typename... Args>
  class Signal {

   public:

    Signal() : current_id_(0) {}

    // copy creates new signal
    Signal(Signal const& other) : current_id_(0) {}

    // connects a member function to this Signal
    template <typename T>
    int connect_member(T *inst, void (T::*func)(Args...)) {
      return connect([=](Args... args) { 
        (inst->*func)(args...); 
      });
    }

    // connects a const member function to this Signal
    template <typename T>
    int connect_member(T *inst, void (T::*func)(Args...) const) {
      return connect([=](Args... args) {
        (inst->*func)(args...); 
      });
    }

    // connects a std::function to the signal. The returned
    // value can be used to disconnect the function again
    int connect(std::function<void(Args...)> const& slot) const {
      slots_.insert(std::make_pair(++current_id_, slot));
      return current_id_;
    }

    // disconnects a previously connected function
    void disconnect(int id) const {
      slots_.erase(id);
    }

    // disconnects all previously connected functions
    void disconnect_all() const {
      slots_.clear();
    }

    // calls all connected functions
    void emit(Args... p) {
      for(auto it : slots_) {
        it.second(p...);
      }
    }

    // assignment creates new Signal
    Signal& operator=(Signal const& other) {
      disconnect_all();
    }

   private:
    mutable std::map<int, std::function<void(Args...)>> slots_;
    mutable int current_id_;
  };

  #endif /* SIGNAL_HPP */
  ```

  How it's called so i can look for myself.
  Did i found overcomplicated example ?

Thanks.

Comment: You "small" questions about syntax are the subject of rich sections in C++ books. Pick a [good one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and learn.

Comment: Too many questions per question, please limit the amount to one.

Comment: Despite answering the question, I also agree with the above and the close votes. You're asking about several pieces of intermediate-level syntax. It's good stuff to learn, but should have been a) searched for (duplicates probably exist); and then b) asked in separate questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking your questions in order:

- `Signal() : current_id_(0) {}`

That's a initialiser list in `Signal`'s constructor. It tells the compiler that `current_id_` should be initialized to 0 when the `Signal` object is constructed using that c'tor.

- `int connect_member(T *inst, void (T::*func)(Args...)) {`

`T::` is a scope-resolution, and `T::*` specifically refers to a member function. The function call `connect_member` expects to receive a pointer-to-`T`, followed by a pointer-to-member-function-of-`T` (which takes unspecified arguments and returns nothing)

- `mutable std::map<int, std::function<void(Args...)>> slots_;`

`slots_` is a data member of `Signal`, of type `map` from integer to function-returning-void. The `mutable` keyword tells the compiler it's ok for `slots_` to be changed even if the owning `Signal` is `const` (for instance, inside a member function declared `const`).